# Get django field "choice" from arbitrary value

Tags: django, python-3.4

I have a django class like this:

```
class my_thing(models.Model):
    AVAILABLE = 1
    NOT_AVAILABLE = 2

    STATUSES = (
                (AVAILABLE, "Available"),
                (NOT_AVAILABLE, "Not available")
                )
    status = models.IntegerField(...., choices = STATUSES)
```

In another bit of code I have the number corresponding to a status, but due to some legacy code I need to compare it via strings (and I don't want to hard code it anywhere other than the model definition - DRY)

So in the code I have the number "1" and I want to get the text "Available".

My current (awful) workaround is to do the following:

```
status_getter = my_thing()
my_thing.status = my_thing.AVAILABLE
comparison_str = status_getter.get_status_display()
```

Is there a better/builtin way to directly access the string value for the field's choices given that I don't have an object of that type already instantiated? I could write a function

```
def get_status_on_value(self, value):
    for tup in STATUSES:
       if tup[0] == value:
         return tup[1]
```

But I have a sneaking suspicion django has a built-in way to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. Your best bet is to convert the CHOICES tuple to a dict and do a lookup:

```
status_dict = dict(my_thing.STATUSES)
return status_dict[value]
```

Comment: Definitely a better solution than my horrible hack.